# Code signing certificates for Java, Adobe AIR, Authenticode, VBS - are they different?

Tags: certificate, code-signing, digital-certificate, jar-signing, code-signing-certificate

We have a code-signing certificate, purchased from GlobalSign for Authenticode signing (as they call it). Now we need to sign Java applet and soon Adobe AIR module (applet?). The question is: from technical point of view is there any difference between certificate-for-Authenticode and certificate-for-Java or certificate-for-AIR, if they are issued by the same CA (say Comodo or GlobalSign)? I don't see a point in buying different certificates if they are replaceable.

I understand that key usage field of certificates must be the same (code signing), but maybe extended code usage or policy or other extension differs in those certificates. I would appreciate if somebody who has code-signing certificates of two or more types issued by one CA could check this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that any code signing certificate will work for any mentioned platform. I asked GlobalSign support about the difference - they didn't respond, however soon after that they have changed their web page and now you would be buying one code signing certificate for all platforms.

Answer (score 5):

There's an explicit statement at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/signing_air_applications.html that:

> "A developer can use any class-3,
>   high-assurance certificate provided by
>   any CA to sign an Adobe AIR
>   application."

Unfortunately, I can't find anything similar for Java.  However, regardless of the minimum certificate requirements for the various platforms, your best bet might be to contact your existing certificate provider to ask if there are any meaningful differences between the certificates they offer for these platforms.

Some of the blah-blah on the Verisign website suggests that the format in which the certificate is delivered to the purchaser is the only real difference between their offerings, but they don't actually state this directly, so who knows...?

Comment: Thank you for the reference. This sheds some light on the topic, though not much. Technically it can be that specifically for AIR any code signing certificate would work, however (a) this can be not the case for others (java, VBS), and (b) there can be some legal restrictions that I have overlooked (I did read GlobalSign's policy on this). As a side note: we use GlobalSign code signing certificate to sign kernel-mode drivers, so it was purchased for a purpose, and now I want to use it for Java modules (in a different project).

Answer (score 2):

From what I gather from RFC 5280, the key usage extensions can only decide whether the certificate is usable for code signing or not. There doesn't seem to be anything in the RFC that can constrain whether you sign Java code or AIR or whatever. This seems to imply that if you can sign one piece of code (or any other kind of non-key data) you can sign any.

That said, there may be CA-specific extensions in your certificate. Without seeing the certificate it's hard to tell if there are limitations.

From a technical perspective, as long as the client (i.e. the browser if we're talking about applets) recognises the CA and is happy with your combination of key usage and certificate type (DIGITAL_SIGNATURE and OBJECT_SIGNING) then you should be fine.

Comment: This is not exactly so, and here's why. For example, key usage for regular SSL certificate and EV SSL certificate is the same. It's policy OID, included into EV SSL certificate which defines that this is EV SSL Certificate. This policy ID is different for each "certified" CA that issues EV SSL certificates, and the list of policy IDs is updated from time to time. So I guess there *can* be some custom extension (or value in Extended Key Usage extension) that specifies that the certificate should be used only for signing certain class of code objects. And this is where the question came from.

Comment: I did suspect that there might be custom extensions that could cause problems but it's not clear from the RFC, nor is it clear that it would even matter if the browser doesn't recognise the extension. Browsers can ignore non-critical extensions that they don't understand, can't they? In any case, I guess I can change my answer to "I don't know". It seems that you need to look at the specifics of the certificate you have. Are you able to post relevant portions of the certificate?

Comment: @Cameron if I had those certificates, there would be no question. I am trying to find out, if it makes sense (from technical or legal point of view) to purchase different certificates for different code object classes. So far it looks like we would have to buy another one (we have one already) and compare them.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, I see your point. I thought you had one certificate that might be enough to inspect, but I agree that comparing two is the best way to answer the question.

Comment: @Cameron I do have one for Authenticode, but it's too generic, i.e. it's applicable to many classes of code objects. AIR and Java certificates are more specific and I don't have them to inspect :(

Comment: @Eugene: You don't need to have bought a certificate to be able to look at one.  You should be able to retrieve the certificate from any signed code package to which you have access.  That said, just because a certificate has an extension doesn't mean that it's actually consumed by the relevant code host, so examining certificates may be useless.